# PHP Decimal-Value in array changes automatically from Point to Comma as Seperator

Tags: multidimensional-array, floating-point, decimalformat, decimal-point

That's strange. Why a decimal value in an array changes automatically from a point- to a comma-seperator? Yes, it's a float, but I don't change the value like with *number_format* or anything, so why is this happening and how to prevent changing the decimal mark?

```
$tmp = array (
array("2017-04-01", 3),
array("2017-04-02", 7),             
array("2017-04-06", 4.8)
);

var_dump($tmp);

$result = "";

foreach ($tmp as $value) {
            $result .= $value[0]." => ".$value[1]." ";
        }

echo $result;
```

Result:

> array(3) {   [0]=>   array(2) {
>       [0]=>
>       string(10) "2017-04-01"
>       [1]=>
>       int(3)   }   [1]=>   array(2) {
>       [0]=>
>       string(10) "2017-04-02"
>       [1]=>
>       int(7)   }   [2]=>   array(2) {
>       [0]=>
>       string(10) "2017-04-06"
>       [1]=>
>       float(4,8)   } }
>
> 2017-04-01 => 3 
>   2017-04-02 => 7 
>   2017-04-06 => 4,8

Comment: It will output a floating point value according to the current locale of the web server. You can change this using the [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) function.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That's apparently the reason. In German we use the comma as the decimal mark, but I need ONLY for this array the unformated version. Is there a way to make an exception in php without switching the local information?

Comment: I suspect you're getting confused here. The number is stored internally without any formatting information. It's only when you coerce it to a string that it chooses how to display it. As such, you only need to use `setlocale()` if you are using a function such as `echo()` or `printf()` or `var_dump()`.